# ограничение доступа к форме с другой формы

Tags: c#, winforms

Можно ли каким-то образом скрыть кнопки на форме которая открывается с другой формы (очень понятно, ага). Кароче есть форма со списком врачей. В системе два пользователя -Администратор и Врач. Администратору доступны кнопки редактирования, добавления и удаления (скрин 1).
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Врачу же показывается та же самая форма, только со скрытыми и недоступными для нажатия кнопками добавления и удаления. Кнопка редактирования данных переименована в "Просмотреть"
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот кусок кода:

```
 private void DoctorFiles_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DoctorListForm doctorListForm = new DoctorListForm();
        doctorListForm.AddDoctor.Enabled = false;
        doctorListForm.AddDoctor.Visible = false;
        doctorListForm.DeleteDoctor.Enabled = false;
        doctorListForm.DeleteDoctor.Visible = false;
        doctorListForm.EditDoctor.Text = "Просмотреть карточку врача";
        doctorListForm.Show();
    }
```

Здесь DoctorListForm - та самая форма которая на пикчах. AddDoctor, DeleteDoctor, EditDoctor - кнопки добавления, удаления, редактирования.

Вся соль в том, что я хочу как-то сделать, чтобы по нажатию кнопки "Просмотреть" врачу открывалось окно просмотра, только тоже со скрытыми кнопками сохранения и очистки полей, в общем ограничить доступ к ней (скрин формы внизу).
[image: форма редактирования на которой надо скрыть кнопки]

Была мысль сделать через потоки, но не втыкаю как нормально проверку на нажатие кнопки с другой формы сделать:

```
 private void DoctorFiles_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DoctorListForm doctorListForm = new DoctorListForm();
        doctorListForm.AddDoctor.Enabled = false;
        doctorListForm.AddDoctor.Visible = false;
        doctorListForm.DeleteDoctor.Enabled = false;
        doctorListForm.DeleteDoctor.Visible = false;
        doctorListForm.EditDoctor.Text = "Просмотреть карточку врача";
        doctorListForm.Show();

        //EditDoctorForm editDoctorForm = new EditDoctorForm(connection, fileId);
        //editDoctorForm.Enabled = false;

        if (doctorListForm.EditDoctor_Click(this, e) /*????*/)
        {
            new System.Threading.Thread(OpenDoctorFile).Start();
        }
    }
    private void OpenDoctorFile()
    {

        EditDoctorForm editDoctorForm = new EditDoctorForm(connection, fileId);
        editDoctorForm.button1.Enabled = false;
        editDoctorForm.button1.Visible = false;
        editDoctorForm.button2.Enabled = false;
        editDoctorForm.button2.Visible = false;
        editDoctorForm.Enabled = false;
        editDoctorForm.Show();
```

Заранее спасибо за ответы!!

Comment: Если в системе два пользователя, то почему нельзя реализовать требуемое поведение исходя из роли пользователя?

Comment: В конструкторе формы добавьте параметр (роль).

Answer (score 1):

**Не нужно управлять контроллами одной формы из другой. Каждая форма должна по максимуму не зависеть от других по части данных и тем более визуализации.**

1. Добавляешь перечисление типа:

   enum FormMode{
   BrowseMode = 1,
   EditMode = 2
   }
2. Добавляешь свойство в открываемую форму:

   ```
   private FormMode FormMode {get;set;} = FormMode.BrowseMode;
   ```
3. Добавляешь его в конструктор
4. Прописываешь правила видимости/доступности контроллов в инициализации формы. Эти правила должны зависеть от FormMode.
5. При попытке открыть форму из нужного места или при нужном праве передаешь нужное значение в конструктор:

   EditDoctorForm editDoctorForm = new EditDoctorForm(connection, fileId, formMode);
   editDoctorForm.Show();